# Send emails in php using mandrill

Tags: php, email, mandrill

I am new to mandrill and am using mandrill to send mails in my php application. Also I've registered my domain in mandril. I got the code to send a mail in mandrill in php. I tried it and its working. But i didn't understand how to send mail without specifying the from mail address in the code. That is the 'from' mail address should be the one which I set default.

I searched a lot, even in mandrill But I couldn't find any answer. Can anyone help me with this..??

I used this code:

```
<?php
try {
$mandrill = new Mandrill('YOUR_API_KEY');
$message = array(
    'html' => '<p>Example HTML content</p>',
    'text' => 'Example text content',
    'subject' => 'example subject',
    'from_email' => 'message.from_email@example.com', //this address should be my default one
    'from_name' => 'Example Name',
    'to' => array(
        array(
            'email' => 'recipient.email@example.com',
            'name' => 'Recipient Name',
            'type' => 'to'
        )
    ),
    'headers' => array('Reply-To' => 'message.reply@example.com'),
    'important' => false,
    'track_opens' => null,
    'track_clicks' => null,
    'auto_text' => null,
    'auto_html' => null,
    'inline_css' => null,
    'url_strip_qs' => null,
    'preserve_recipients' => null,
    'view_content_link' => null,
    'bcc_address' => 'message.bcc_address@example.com',
    'tracking_domain' => null,
    'signing_domain' => null,
    'return_path_domain' => null,
    'merge' => true,
    'global_merge_vars' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'merge1',
            'content' => 'merge1 content'
        )
    ),
    'merge_vars' => array(
        array(
            'rcpt' => 'recipient.email@example.com',
            'vars' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'merge2',
                    'content' => 'merge2 content'
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    'tags' => array('password-resets'),
    'subaccount' => 'customer-123',
    'google_analytics_domains' => array('example.com'),
    'google_analytics_campaign' => 'message.from_email@example.com',
    'metadata' => array('website' => 'www.example.com'),
    'recipient_metadata' => array(
        array(
            'rcpt' => 'recipient.email@example.com',
            'values' => array('user_id' => 123456)
        )
    ),
    'attachments' => array(
        array(
            'type' => 'text/plain',
            'name' => 'myfile.txt',
            'content' => 'ZXhhbXBsZSBmaWxl'
        )
    ),
    'images' => array(
        array(
            'type' => 'image/png',
            'name' => 'IMAGECID',
            'content' => 'ZXhhbXBsZSBmaWxl'
        )
    )
);
$async = false;
$ip_pool = 'Main Pool';
$send_at = 'example send_at';
$result = $mandrill->messages->send($message, $async, $ip_pool, $send_at);
print_r($result);
/*
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [email] => recipient.email@example.com
            [status] => sent
            [reject_reason] => hard-bounce
            [_id] => abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123
        )

)
*/
} catch(Mandrill_Error $e) {
// Mandrill errors are thrown as exceptions
echo 'A mandrill error occurred: ' . get_class($e) . ' - ' . $e->getMessage();
// A mandrill error occurred: Mandrill_Unknown_Subaccount - No subaccount exists with the id 'customer-123'
throw $e;
}
?>
```

Comment: If i correctly remember the Mandrill Api, you cannot send mails without from_email and hope that he just uses the Mandrill Account Email. Only "from_name" is optional

Comment: I know from_email is inevitable for sending the mail. But my question is I've added my domain in mandrill, when am sending a mail the 'from' address should be the one I've added as my domain. How it can be done??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set a default from_address. You will have to include it each time via your API call.

Your domain is something else, by adding a domain you add it to the whitelist of domains that can talk your Mandrill account via the API.

Comment: Now I understand the problem. Thanks